# QtCreator: unify QtCreatorCodeStyle with clang-format

Tags: c++, qt-creator, clang-format

I would like to know if there is a simple way to convert a qt creator codestyle (xml file) into a clang-format file?

I have the following configuration for my c++ code, generated from qtcreator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE QtCreatorCodeStyle>
<!-- Written by QtCreator 4.2.1, 2017-03-09T12:29:05. -->
<qtcreator>
 <data>
  <variable>CodeStyleData</variable>
  <valuemap type="QVariantMap">
   <value type="bool" key="AlignAssignments">false</value>
   <value type="bool" key="AutoSpacesForTabs">false</value>
   <value type="bool" key="BindStarToIdentifier">false</value>
   <value type="bool" key="BindStarToLeftSpecifier">true</value>
   <value type="bool" key="BindStarToRightSpecifier">false</value>
   <value type="bool" key="BindStarToTypeName">true</value>
   <value type="bool" key="ExtraPaddingForConditionsIfConfusingAlign">true</value>
   <value type="bool" key="IndentAccessSpecifiers">false</value>
   <value type="bool" key="IndentBlockBody">true</value>
   <value type="bool" key="IndentBlockBraces">false</value>
   <value type="bool" key="IndentBlocksRelativeToSwitchLabels">true</value>
   <value type="bool" key="IndentClassBraces">false</value>
   <value type="bool" key="IndentControlFlowRelativeToSwitchLabels">true</value>
   <value type="bool" key="IndentDeclarationsRelativeToAccessSpecifiers">true</value>
   <value type="bool" key="IndentEnumBraces">false</value>
   <value type="bool" key="IndentFunctionBody">true</value>
   <value type="bool" key="IndentFunctionBraces">false</value>
   <value type="bool" key="IndentNamespaceBody">false</value>
   <value type="bool" key="IndentNamespaceBraces">false</value>
   <value type="int" key="IndentSize">2</value>
   <value type="bool" key="IndentStatementsRelativeToSwitchLabels">true</value>
   <value type="bool" key="IndentSwitchLabels">true</value>
   <value type="int" key="PaddingMode">2</value>
   <value type="bool" key="ShortGetterName">true</value>
   <value type="bool" key="SpacesForTabs">false</value>
   <value type="int" key="TabSize">2</value>
  </valuemap>
 </data>
 <data>
  <variable>DisplayName</variable>
  <value type="QString">Google</value>
 </data>
</qtcreator>
```

But I can't find the clang-format equivalent for most of these variables.
My clang-format file in the beautifier plugin is similar but not identical, which leads to a mess in my git diffs every time.

Answer (score 2):

I went through the *QtCreator* settings and came up with the following general mapping. The settings are listed in the same order they appear in the *Qt Creator 4.10.2* Code Style dialog box, which helps to identify the sometimes cryptic names.

Settings labeled N/A are things `clang-format` seems not to support. (According to the docs `clang-format` intentionally supports only a small set of fixed styles and is not a general-purpose formatter.)

I haven't tried to match specific setting values or the more complex combinations, but this list should serve as a starting point to figure it out.

```
QtCreator                                     Clang-format
---------                                     ------------

[GENERAL]
SpacesForTabs                                 UseTab
TabSize                                       TabWidth
IndentSize                                    IndentWidth
PaddingMode                                   UseTab

[CONTENT]
IndentAccessSpecifiers                        AccessModifierOffset
IndentDeclarationsRelativeToAccessSpecifiers  N/A
IndentFunctionBody                            N/A
IndentBlockBody                               N/A
IndentNamespaceBody                           NamespaceIndentation

[BRACES]
# Qt's implied style matches Clang BreakBeforeBraces=Allman
# Qt's IndentX options match Clang's BreakBeforeBraces=GNU
# to customize GNU style, see:
IndentClassBraces       BraceWrapping:AfterClass:IndentBraces
IndentNamespaceBraces   BraceWrapping:AfterNamespace:IndentBraces
IndentEnumBraces        BraceWrapping:AfterEnum:IndentBraces
IndentFunctionBraces    BraceWrapping:AfterFunction:IndentBraces
IndentBlockBraces       N/A

[SWITCH]
IndentSwitchLabels                            IndentCaseLabels
IndentStatementsRelativeToSwitchLabels        N/A
IndentBlocksRelativeToSwitchLabels            N/A
IndentControlFlowRelativeToSwitchLabels       N/A

[ALIGNMENT]
AlignAssignments                              AlignOperands
ExtraPaddingForConditionsIfConfusingAlign     N/A

[POINTERS AND REFERENCES]
BindStarToIdentifier                          PointerAlignment
BindStarToTypeName                            PointerAlignment
BindStarToLeftSpecifier                       PointerAlignment
BindStarToRightSpecifier                      PointerAlignment

[?]
AutoSpacesForTabs                             N/A (editor setting)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get an example config from the installed formats, e.g. llvm:

```
clang-format -style=llvm -dump-config > .clang-format
```

So you need  the text and the key attribute of the "value" elements.
The Format is mostly.
:

with python and lxml:

```
with open(xml_path) as xml_file: 
xml_content = xml_file.read()
tree = etree.parse(xml_path)
elements = tree.findall("value")
fileBuffer =""
for e in elements:
    filebuffer += e.attr["key"] + ": " + e.text + "\n"
```

its not tested